# Flutter pluto_layout won't update tabs

Tags: flutter, setstate, state-management

I am using pluto_layout ([GitHub](https://github.com/bosskmk/pluto_layout)) in my FlutterApp for Windows.
But I don't understand how to update the contents of the tabs.

The usual way I do it is using setState. But no changes can be seen.
On the GitHub Page is a usage example.
Below I am using that and I implement a simple counter in the left tab.
When I replace the left tab

```
left: PlutoLayoutContainer(
          child: PlutoLayoutTabs(
            items: [
              PlutoLayoutTabItem(
                id: 'left1',
                title: 'left1',
                tabViewBuilder: (e) => const Text('left1'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

with

```
left: PlutoLayoutContainer(
          child: PlutoLayoutTabs(
            items: [
              PlutoLayoutTabItem(
                id: 'left1',
                title: 'left1',
                tabViewWidget: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('number of times clicked: ${counter}'),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          counter++;
                          print(counter);
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'click',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

the visuals won't update.

Any ideas on how to update the tabs would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you wrap your PlutoLayoutContainer in stateful widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok when I put the counter in a new Widget it works fine.
For example in a widget like this:

```
class Count extends StatefulWidget {
  const Count({super.key});

  @override
  State<Count> createState() => _CountState();
}

class _CountState extends State<Count> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('${counter}'),
        TextButton(onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            counter++;
            print(counter);
          });
        }, child: Text('click'),)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And in the above example I replace the Column in tabViewWidget with the Count Widget.